# Cannot open Metasploit

Tags: 12.04, metasploit

I installed Metasploit on 12.04 and it is ready to use, but I don't know how to run it. I have tried to execute this file: `metasploit-latest-linux-installer.run` and it starts to boot up  then it says:

```
There has been an error.
This installer requires root privileges. Please become superuser before executing the installer.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using sudo in-front of the file name?

For example `sudo metasploit-latest-linux-installer.run` then type your password.

If that does not work, you can try `sudo su` and run the command. Although, I highly suggest you not dropping down to `su` as it can be very dangerous.

Comment: Yeah su to root can be really damaging if you leave the keyboard with a root shell open  they can really mess up your installation. However yes sudo su can be dangerous as it leaves a root shell open. However if you are on a multiuser computer you can su to another user which is no  different than logging into that user. However it is not that often you want to do this.